# Mathematics help. Preliminary grid checking assistance. (Supercover Z)

Tags: mathematics

**Problem outline:** A ray passes through a gridcell. The gridcell's max z's must be compared to the ray segment's min z. This is the preliminary check, so it must be quick.
2 values must be obtained, the 2 points on the ray segment which are directly outside of the grid.
To determine the z values, the distance of the ray from these 2 points must be obtained.
The red shows the points (and distance) of the ray of z values that must be checked as max and min.
[image]

**The sloppy solution**
Instead of getting the points directly touching, calculate the hypotenuse and offset it doing various calculations. I tried this way and there are a lot of operations to be done. I am not sure if this is the best way.
(cant upload more than 3 pics)

**The sloppiest (and possibly best) solution**
The best sloppy solution would be to create a line offset by the hypotenuse, and have it congruent to the main line then use line_line_collision to determine the distance for point 1 then subtract that distance by hypotenuse*2 for point 2.
[image: The sloppiest solution]

**The streamlined solution**
The best way would have the z's directly retrieved as part of the actual supercover algorithm.
Unfortunately retrieving the n values or error values in tandem with n values couldn't actually yield me the intersection points of the line and grid. My brain is utterly fried at the moment.
My code is here, possibly someone can find an inherent method to retrieve the intersection points of the line and grid.

```
iX=0 iY=0 s=16 res=8
repeat (res*res)
{
draw_rectangle(iX*s,iY*s,(iX+1)*s,(iY+1)*s,1)
iX+=1;
if iX>res-1
    {iY+=1; iX=0}
}
if mouse_check_button(mb_left) direction+=5

xfrom=mouse_x/s yfrom=mouse_y/s l=300

vecx=lengthdir_x(l,direction)/s vecy=lengthdir_y(l,direction)/s
direction=point_direction(0,0,vecx,vecy)
xto=xfrom+vecx yto=yfrom+vecy

draw_line(xfrom*s,yfrom*s,xto*s,yto*s)
x0=xfrom y0=yfrom x1=xto y1=yto it=0

{
    dx = abs(x1 - x0);
    dy = abs(y1 - y0);

    x = floor(x0);
    y = floor(y0);

    n = 1;
    var x_inc, y_inc;
    error=0;

    if (dx == 0)
    {
        x_inc = 0;
        error = 1000000;
    }
    else if (x1 > x0)
    {
        x_inc = 1
        n += (floor(x1)) - x;
        error = (floor(x0) + 1 - x0) * dy;
    }
    else
    {
        x_inc = -1
        n += x - (floor(x1));
        error = (x0 - floor(x0)) * dy;
    }

    if (dy == 0)
    {
        y_inc = 0;
        error -= 1000000;
    }
    else if (y1 > y0)
    {
        y_inc = 1
        n += (floor(y1)) - y;
        error -= (floor(y0) + 1 - y0) * dx;
    }
    else
    {
        y_inc = -1
        n += y - (floor(y1));
        error -= (y0 - floor(y0)) * dx;
    }
mn=n
    for (n=n; n > 0; n-=1)
    {

   draw_set_color(merge_color(c_red,c_white,it))     
   draw_rectangle(x*s, y*s,x*s+s,y*s+s,1)
        it+=1
        draw_set_color(c_green)
        draw_circle((xfrom+lengthdir_x(it+.5,direction))*s,(yfrom+lengthdir_y(it+.5,direction))*s,2,0)draw_set_color(c_red)
        draw_circle((xfrom+lengthdir_x(it-.5,direction))*s,(yfrom+lengthdir_y(it-.5,direction))*s,2,0)
draw_set_color(c_black)
        if (error > 0)
        {
            y += y_inc;
            error -= dx;
        }
        else
        {
            x += x_inc;
            error += dy;
        }
    }
}
```

There are some other stuff I would like to know...such as 3d triangle/line collisions, but I don't want to boggle the thread down with too much information at the moment...

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackExchange. I reverted your edit because here, when the question is 'solved', we write an answer and mark it as accepted. You can write answers to your own question, and mark them as accepted, it's perfectly acceptable :) In any case, we don't change the title of the question to 'solved'.